# Flutter image_picker not change language on camera

Tags: flutter, localization, imagepicker

I expect the friends who use image_picker on Flutter to help with language. The language of the phone is Spanish, but when it enters the phone camera to take pictures, it looks English. I couldn't see a place where I could change the language. How do you change the language in Image_picker?

Language Spanish but screenshot below..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/20LaX.jpg

**Edit:**

*before:*

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
```

*after:*

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>ru,en,tr,es</string>
```

doing this way, the problem is solved.

Comment: Can you please post some code or some more information on what you have tried?

Comment: i using image_picker: ^0.6.3+4 version 
and 
code side -> 
File imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

that is all.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the code part please?

Comment: You should have written the answer separately and not as an edit.